# Undo accidentally fetched remote rebase

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I created a bunch of git tags while testing a deploy script. I intended to delete the tags and remove them, then flatten a bunch of minute commits into one, but because I did part of this work from home, and part from my office, I needed to push to remote in between. I successfully deleted all the tags and was able to flatten the commits with a `rebase`, but somehow *that change* didn't make it to remote, and I pulled a completely unnecessary *branch* that still contains all those individual commits. Here's what the top of the graph looks like now:

[image: git graph]

What I want is to get rid of the rightmost line altogether, because it's all flattened into the "Better documentation" in the left line. But when I try to re-rebase, I get errors:

```
pick 7a6f13e Testing deploy script
pick f1b5ee2 Better documentation.
f fea906d testing deploy script
f 7bf549c Testing deploys cript
f b5c0cbf testing deploy script
f 355f993 test deploy
f bd96545 deploy test
f 6124b6c deploy test
f 7beca06 test deploy
f fb4cd70 deploy tests
f 59f343a deploy test
f 769d677 test deploy
f c6434d8 test deploy
f c949c9f deploy test
f fa00bc5 deploy test
f 2a3f53c deploy tests
pick befc523 Better documentation.
```

**error: could not apply 7a6f13e... Testing deploy script**

Ultimately, I just want to get rid of the righthand side of that graph, since it's entirely redundant. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push with a force the side that you want:

```
git push origin branch_name -f
```

Make sure you warn the others that are working with you that you did this. They will have to rebase any work they did on top of your last push to where this branch will be now.

Comment: The thing is, the "branch" on the right doesn't have a name. (If it does, I didn't name it and I don't see it in any references.) How do I reference it?

Comment: It's the second parent of master so `master^2` would reference that. You can make master point to it with `git reset --hard master^2` when you have master checked out (it's your current branch). If you don't have it checked out, you can move the master branch to point to it with `git push . +master^2:master` and then push it up with `git push origin master -f`. (+ and -f do the same thing, but go in different places)

Comment: If you just want to update the remote's master, just push that commit to master on the remote: `git push origin master^2:master -f`.